# Datagridview Column sort in descending order

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to sort my datagrid view column which is non data bound. so please help me . following is the code

```
private void dgvDailyEntry_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {

        this.dgvDailyEntry.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["sno"].Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();      
    }
```

[sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk9Um.jpg)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If it's not bound, I'd assume you have a datatable assigned as datasource. If you can sort the data while obtaining the datatable, the best is to sort it right there. If you can't (i.e. data are generated in random order), sort the datatable then.

C#

```
Datatable dt;    // that is the source datatable
DataView SortedDataView = new DataView();
SortedDataView = dt.DefaultView;
SortedDataView.Sort = "COlumnNameToSortBy DESC";
dt = SortedDataView.ToTable();
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim dt as Datatable    ' that is the source datatable
Dim SortedDataView As New DataView
SortedDataView = dt.DefaultView
SortedDataView.Sort = "COlumnNameToSortBy DESC" 
dt = SortedDataView.ToTable()
```

If you somehow don't have datatable, I'd certainly recommend to implement it. It's a good practice even if you don't need sorting and such.